# Class constructor cannot be invoked without 'new' - typescript with commonjs

Tags: node.js, typescript, commonjs

I am making server side chat with colyseus (node game server framework). Im using typescript with module:commonjs because colyseus is built upon commonjs.

I have class `ChatRoom` that extends `Colyseus.Room`. 
At run-time I get this error:

```
Class constructor Room cannot be invoked without 'new'.
```

And the trouble in javascript:

```
function ChatRoom() {
   return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
}
```

from typescript class:

```
import {Room} from "colyseus";

export class ChatRoom extends Room {

    onInit(options) {
        console.log("BasicRoom created!", options);
    }

    onJoin(client) {
        this.broadcast(`${ client.sessionId } joined.`);
    }

    onLeave(client) {
        this.broadcast(`${ client.sessionId } left.`);
    }

    onMessage(client, data) {
        console.log("BasicRoom received message from", client.sessionId, ":", data);
        this.broadcast(`(${ client.sessionId }) ${ data.message }`);
    }

    onDispose() {
        console.log("Dispose BasicRoom");
    }
  }
```

The error is easily skipped when troubled row is removed after compilation. But the base class is not created and this is not a complete solution.

I googled the issue and it seems to relate to babel transpiler, though I don't use babel. I only use tsc / tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

TypeScript transpiles a class to its ES5 counterpart, but this way it's necessary that entire class hierarchy is transpiled to ES5.

In case parent class is untranspiled (native class or imported ES6 class, including the ones that were transpiled with Babel), this won't work, because TypeScript relies on `var instance = Parent.call(this, ...) || this` trick to call parent constructor, while ES6 classes should be called only with `new`.

This problem should be solved in Node.js by setting TypeScript [`target` option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) to `es6` or higher. Modern Node.js versions support ES6 classes, there is no need to transpile them.

The same problem [applies to Babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860043/javascript-es6-typeerror-class-constructor-client-cannot-be-invoked-without-ne).

Comment: Thanks. This works:
tsconfig.compilerOptions: {target : "es6",..}

Comment: ...or also, in case you need es5 support, making sure that all the hierarchy is compiled with target: es5. my two cents!

Comment: Here's a table of which `target` to use for your version of Node https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Node-Target-Mapping

Answer (score 30):

For those who are using [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node), it could be possible that your `tsconfig.json` is unable to be loaded by **ts-node**.

1. Make sure you've set the below option for `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        ...
    }
}
```

2. Try `ts-node --script-mode` or use `--project` to specify the path of your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: This solved my issue! I had to switch over from ES5 to ES6 and it worked

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I tried this but I am unable to follow what you are mentioning in `Step-2`. I am using `Nuxt.js`.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/69915969/7584240

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 Are you using ts-node? When using ts-node, we call something like `ts-node ./index.ts` to start our app. And according to my answer, we can use `ts-node --script-mode ./index.ts` instead.

Comment: Using `ts-node --project tsconfig.json` did it for me!

Comment: Unfortunately, I created a tsconfig.json as you suggested but I am still getting that error.

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same problem using javascript, webpack, and babel (but no TypeScript).

I found a solution based on
[ES6/Babel Class constructor cannot be invoked without 'new'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44625868/es6-babel-class-constructor-cannot-be-invoked-without-new)

I needed to explicitly include colyseus in my babel loader. Below is the snippet in my webpack config file:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: /colyseus/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```