# Javascript ES6 TypeError: Class constructor Client cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, syntax-error

I have a class written in Javascript ES6. When I try to execute `nodemon` command I always see this error `TypeError: Class constructor Client cannot be invoked without 'new'`

The full error is mentioned below:

```
/Users/akshaysood/Blockchain/fabricSDK/dist/application/Transaction.js:45
        return (0, _possibleConstructorReturn3.default)(this, (FBClient.__proto__ || (0, _getPrototypeOf2.default)(FBClient)).call(this, props));
                                                                                                                              ^

TypeError: Class constructor Client cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at new FBClient (/Users/akshaysood/Blockchain/fabricSDK/dist/application/Transaction.js:45:127)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/akshaysood/Blockchain/fabricSDK/dist/application/Transaction.js:195:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:585:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/akshaysood/Blockchain/fabricSDK/dist/routes/users.js:11:20)
```

What I am trying to do is, I have created a class and then created an instance of that class. Then I am trying to export that variable.

The class structure is defined below:

```
class FBClient extends FabricClient{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

<<< FUNCTIONS >>>

}
```

How I am trying to export the variable ->

```
var client = new FBClient();
client.loadFromConfig(config);

export default client = client;
```

You can find the full code here --> [Link](https://hastebin.com/kecacenita.js).
Code generated by Babel --> [Link](https://hastebin.com/fabewecumo.js).

Comment: I'm not sure that you can export the instance of a class. I think you have to export the class, import it in another, then create the instance there

Comment: @bwalshy - You can export any value, including an instance of a class.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This code can not be run online as it requires Blockchain module.

Comment: @AkshaySood - The error is clearly not about blockchain stuff, it's about basic class definition and instantiation. Please read that MCVE link. You're not expected to post all your code. You're expected to work through a process producing a minimal replicating example. You haven't even shown us the class where the error is occurring.

Comment: Are you using Babel to transpile your code? [(possibly related issue, but just a guess)](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7840)

Comment: @Pointy Yes I am using Babel

Comment: Notice that you should not use `class` syntax anyway if you want your module to export a singleton object. If you think you need instances, then you should export the class itself.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

The problem is that the class extends native ES6 class and is transpiled to ES5 with Babel. Transpiled classes cannot extend native classes, at least without additional measures.

```
class TranspiledFoo extends NativeBar {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

results in something like

```
function TranspiledFoo() {
  var _this = NativeBar.call(this) || this;
  return _this;
}
// prototypically inherit from NativeBar
```

Since ES6 classes should be only called with `new`, `NativeBar.call` results in error.

ES6 classes are supported in any recent Node version, they shouldn't be transpiled. `es2015` should be excluded from Babel configuration, it's preferable to use [`env` preset set to `node` target](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env/).

The same problem [applies to TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50203532/3731501). The compiler should be properly configured to not transpile classes in order for them to inherit from native or Babel classes.

Comment: As the answer says. Change Babel configuration to not transpile to ES5. `es2015` preset is responsible for this behaviour.

Comment: If I do not transpile ES6 into ES5 using Babel. It throws error :unexpected token import:

Comment: The manual covers that, https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env/ . Use 'target node'.

Comment: estus. Do you know how to use ES6 in Nodejs without Babel?

Comment: Just use it, all features except ES modules are available, http://node.green/ . ES modules are experimental and need .mjs extension, you may want to use `require` and `module.exports` for now. Babel is useful only for using features that are not there, like class fields and decorators.

Comment: Ok So that means we can not use `export` & `import` without babel? Can we use `classes` & `constructors` and other features without babel?

Comment: Yes, we can use export and import, but this feature is experimental and isn't very practical in its current implementation, see https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html , I'd suggest to stick to CJS modules for real work. Yes, we can use them, see http://node.green/

Comment: For me i had to remove `'use babel';`! Thanks!!

Comment: How stupid is it that `typeof class A {} === 'function'` yet `A.call()` throws an error?

Comment: @jchook Technically it works like `function A() { if (!new.target) throw new Error('cannot be invoked without new') }`. `A` has its terms but it's definitely a function.

Comment: Please do keep in mind that, while this would work okay for a node (and that's enough to answer the question), it won't help much if you're trying to target a browser.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK Indeed, at least if this means the support of legacy browsers (browser app shouldn't necessarily be ES5 in 2020). If there's a class that extends built-in class (Error, Promise, etc.), it should be extended in a special way to be compatible with ES5, this is covered in other questions on SO. If a class extends native ES6 class, it's the existence of untranspiled class in ES5 app that is a real issue.

Answer (score 38):

I was transpiling not Javascript but Typescript, and ran into the same problem.

I edited the Typescript compiler config file, `tsconfig.json`, to generate ES2017 Javascript code:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2017",
```

instead of whatever the default is, ES2015?  — then all worked fine.

(Maybe this answer can be helpful for people who use Typescript and find this question when they search for the same error message, like I did.)

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me as well. 
changed "target": "es5" to >> "target": "es2017"

Answer (score 17):

For those who are using [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node), it could be possible that your `tsconfig.json` is unable to be loaded by **ts-node**.

1. Make sure you've set the below option for `tsconfig.json`:

```
    {
        "compilerOptions": {
            "target": "ES6",
            ...
        }
    }
```

2. Try `ts-node --script-mode` or use `--project` to specify the path of your `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 8):

In `package.json` you can use targets configuration with `@babel/preset-env`.
set the `esmodules` as 'true'.

Below is the example how I am using in my file:

```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "esmodules": true
          }
        }
      ],
      "@babel/preset-react",
      "@babel/preset-flow"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

For Angular 9+ this can be probably a matter of using typescript compilation flags also:

- `downlevelIteration`
- `importHelpers`

More info hereL https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#downlevelIteration.

Try to use this flags in your `tsconfig.josn`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        ...
    }
}
```

Without `"importHelpers": true` it should also works.

---

> This solution is mostly for Angular 9+ and ngcc compiler - this was an issue that occur for Angular 11. A custom configuration (custom ng-packgr config - Angular CLI library generating was introduced in Angular 6) for packages was maintained since there was Angular 4+ in the project. After miagration these packages to Angular 9+ libraries (projects folder) the error started occuring. I found that these flags (sctrictly downlevelIteration) solve exactly the problem.

Comment: And also target to es6

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using babel and simple typescript. I got the error in material. Try to reduce the versions and bring them down to similar versions. My packages were having variety of versions.I solved the issue by lowering the package versions of packages like cdk, material.

[image: Check the image of my final package.json]

Answer (score 1):

Check your "entities" array in appmodule.ts
I also missed that. When I kept the entity name that is used in query, issue resolved.
Hope this answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

i used wrote before my ObjectId in nextjs and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I wrote new before ObjectId in my Mongodb insertMany(), and it removes my error

Answer (score 0):

If you have already all these configurations on tsconfig and still it doesn't work maybe you have tsconfig.base file.
try to chenge it too.

Answer (score 0):

**You can wrap instead of extending if you're not in TypeScript**

In my situation, I didn't want to change the babel configuration (yet) and wanted to make the logic just work.
Understanding a transpiled class cannot extend a native ES6 class I decided to simply wrap the base class, add functions to it and expose it (shoulnd't work in TypeScript).

My original code was something like:

```js
import BaseClass from 'other-library';
class MyClass extends BaseClass {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);

    this.on('event', this.action);
  }

  action(args) {
    // Custom logic for extending the BaseClass
  }
  addedAction(args) {
    // Custom logic for extending the BaseClass
  }
};

new MyClass({ args: ... }); // This throws "Class constructor BaseClass cannot be invoked without 'new'"
```

And I changed inheritance to wrapping like this:

```js
import BaseClass from 'other-library';
class MyClass {
  constructor(options) {
    this.wrapped = new BaseClass(options);
    this.wrapped.addedAction = this.addedAction.bind(this);
    this.wrapped.on('event', this.action);
  }

  action(args) {
    // Custom logic for extending the BaseClass
  }
  addedAction(args) {
    this.wrapped.doSomething();
  }
};

// To get the base instance:
new MyClass({ args: ... }).wrapped;
```

Notice that after creating an instance of `MyClass` I simply access `.wrapped` to get the `BaseClass` instance

Answer (score -10):

I hope you have already been able to solve your problem, here is my solution for this error:

```
class indexRoutes
{
    
    public  router: Router= Router();
}
const INDEX_ROUTES = new indexRoutes();
export default INDEX_ROUTES.router;
```