# Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor ScratchStorage cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript

When I use package `clipcc-storage` in the code below, the console threw an error `Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor ScratchStorage cannot be invoked without 'new'`. I previously disabled the ES6 module conversion in the package according to the answer in Stack Overflow, but it doesn't work. What should I do?

ps: the package can be found in [npmjs.com](https://npmjs.com)

```
import ScratchStorage from 'clipcc-storage';

import defaultProject from './default-project';

// eslint-disable-next-line no-warning-comments
/**
 * Wrapper for ScratchStorage which adds default web sources.
 * @todo make this more configurable
 */
class Storage extends ScratchStorage {
    constructor () {
        super();
        this.cacheDefaultProject();
    }
    addOfficialScratchWebStores () {
        this.addWebStore(
            [this.AssetType.Project],
            this.getProjectGetConfig.bind(this),
            this.getProjectCreateConfig.bind(this),
            this.getProjectUpdateConfig.bind(this)
        );
        this.addWebStore(
            [this.AssetType.ImageVector, this.AssetType.ImageBitmap, this.AssetType.Sound],
            this.getAssetGetConfig.bind(this),
            // We set both the create and update configs to the same method because
            // storage assumes it should update if there is an assetId, but the
            // asset store uses the assetId as part of the create URI.
            this.getAssetCreateConfig.bind(this),
            this.getAssetCreateConfig.bind(this)
        );
        this.addWebStore(
            [this.AssetType.Sound],
            asset => `static/extension-assets/scratch3_music/${asset.assetId}.${asset.dataFormat}`
        );
    }
    setProjectHost (projectHost) {
        this.projectHost = projectHost;
    }
    setProjectUploadHost (projectUploadHost) {
        this.projectUploadHost = projectUploadHost;
    }
    getProjectGetConfig (projectAsset) {
        return `${this.projectHost}${projectAsset.assetId}.json`;
    }
    getProjectCreateConfig () {
        return {
            url: `${this.projectUploadHost}`,
            withCredentials: true
        };
    }
    getProjectUpdateConfig (projectAsset) {
        return {
            url: `${this.projectUploadHost}${projectAsset.assetId}`,
            withCredentials: true
        };
    }
    setAssetHost (assetHost) {
        this.assetHost = assetHost;
    }
    getAssetGetConfig (asset) {
        return `${this.assetHost}${asset.assetId}.${asset.dataFormat}`;
    }
    getAssetCreateConfig (asset) {
        return {
            // There is no such thing as updating assets, but storage assumes it
            // should update if there is an assetId, and the asset store uses the
            // assetId as part of the create URI. So, force the method to POST.
            // Then when storage finds this config to use for the "update", still POSTs
            method: 'post',
            url: `${this.projectUploadHost}/asset/create/${asset.assetId}?type=${asset.dataFormat}`,
            withCredentials: true
        };
    }
    setTranslatorFunction (translator) {
        this.translator = translator;
        this.cacheDefaultProject();
    }
    cacheDefaultProject () {
        const defaultProjectAssets = defaultProject(this.translator);
        defaultProjectAssets.forEach(asset =>
            this.builtinHelper._store(
                this.AssetType[asset.assetType],
                this.DataFormat[asset.dataFormat],
                asset.data,
                asset.id
            )
        );
    }
}

const storage = new Storage();

export default storage;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this problem is caused by ES5-ES6 transpile issue, you may need to transpile the ScratchStorage alone with other codes, depends on your tools, the config is different, for me using vue just change vue.config.js and add

```
transpileDependencies: ['scratch-storage'],
```

you can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860043/javascript-es6-typeerror-class-constructor-client-cannot-be-invoked-without-ne) for more tech information