# Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Platform cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I've installed the Angular CDK in order to use PrimeNG's dropdown component but it throws an error.

I've added this in my app.module.ts:

```js
import {DropdownModule} from 'primeng/dropdown';
```

And installed the Angular CDK by simply typing in the following:

```
npm install @angular/cdk --save
```

Comment: Is this issue the same as the one that you're facing?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860043/javascript-es6-typeerror-class-constructor-client-cannot-be-invoked-without-ne  -----  If so, avoid transpiling to ES5 (See the selected answer)

Comment: i dont think so and what is ES5

Comment: Different versions of ECMAScript (the standard on which JavaScript is based) follow different rules. Many apps use "babel" (or a similar tool) to transpile modern JS to follow the rules of an older version, such as ECMAScript 5 (ie, "ES5"). The answer to the linked question suggests that this can be a bad idea since the transpiled code might now ignore some of the rules of ES6.  ----  The error you see means the code is breaking an ES6 rule (that class constructors must use the `new` keyword). One possible cause could be if your build tool converts your app to the ES5 version. I don't know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue. Check your cdk version in your package.json

I solved installing an older version of cdk 10:

```
npm i @angular/cdk@9.2.4 --save
```

Answer (score 3):

In case someone has the same issue while trying to implement material design with angular material, rollback both material and cdk packages to an older version with:

```
npm i @angular/cdk@9.2.4 @angular/material@9.2.4 --save
```

I hope someone proposes a better approach that enables using the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

In file tsconfig.json,

add this line-  `"target": "es5",`

Comment: `{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}`