# How do I troubleshoot Angular error after installing Font Awesome

Tags: angular

Here is the error I am getting after installing font awesome.

> Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Platform cannot be invoked
> without 'new'
> at Module../node_modules/@angular/cdk/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/platform.js
> (platform.js:78)
> at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:79)
> at Module../node_modules/@angular/cdk/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/scrolling.js
> (scrolling.js:1)
> at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:79)
> at Module../node_modules/primeng/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/primeng-dropdown.js
> (primeng-dropdown.js:1)
> at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:79)
> at Module../src/app/story-editor/choice-editor/choice-editor.component.ts
> (choice-editor.component.ts:1)
> at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:79)
> at Module../src/app/story-editor/story-editor.component.ts (story-editor.component.ts:1)
> at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:79)

I have searched for answers, found a stackoverflow question, tried the solution (downgrade the cdk version) but it didn't work for me. What I would really like to know is what is the best method for troubleshooting something like this and figuring out what the cause is.

It appears to be related to a dropdown component, and may be related to some dependency conflict from installing font awesome, but I am not 100% sure. Any guidance in troubleshooting this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not really easy to know the reason always. Mostly it's hidden in name of files you know from developing yourself. Look at the given line numbers then.

This one may help, because you are also seem to use prime-ng: [Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Platform cannot be invoked without 'new'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62590050/uncaught-typeerror-class-constructor-platform-cannot-be-invoked-without-new)

Other case could be that your angular CLI version mismatches with the ivy renderer, which came with Angular v9.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I saw this stack overflow, and tried downgrading the cdk, but to no avail. It is frustrating because my code was working until I installed font awesome, but uninstalling it doesn't fix the problem...

Comment: if you use version control, id recommend going to the last version of package.json that worked for you and nuking your npm folder and reinstalling the dependencies.  If you have floating version number dependencies, one of them may have made a breaking change.  If you are installing your dependencies both locally and globally, it is really bad practice and some dependencies can get jumbled.  I had angular protractor installed both locally and globally on a test machine before and it was always confused which selenium webdriver version to use.  Good luck.

Comment: I was eventually able to get back up and running. I downgraded the cdk, but i was still getting errors until I restarted Visual Studio Code. I have to assume something got cached....

Comment: @Jonathan Niu - I do use source control, and it was when I reverted but I STILL got application errors after a full rebuild that I realized something was borked with VSC. After a restart, things worked again even after the  CDK downgrade. Not sure what specifically went wrong...