# Class constructor cannot be invoked without 'new' for TSdx package

Tags: typescript, babeljs, commonjs, tsdx

I created a npm package using [TSdx](https://tsdx.io/) for a small [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) reporter. If I use that package in another project, I get the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor BaseReporter cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at new ExampleReporter (..\dist\example-reporter.cjs.development.js:37:26)
```

The `ExampleReporter` inherits from the `BaseReporter` class provided by Jest.

```
import BaseReporter from '@jest/reporters/build/base_reporter';

export class ExampleReporter extends BaseReporter {
  // ...
}
```

As mentioned in [Class constructor cannot be invoked without 'new'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51860850), it can be fixed by setting up Babel. But I couldn't find a working solution with the TSdx documentation.

How can I configure the TSdx `build`?

---

You can reproduce the issue using the watch mode.

```
$ npx tsdx watch --onSuccess node .
...
  Watching for changes

Welcome to Node.js v12.18.2.
Type ".help" for more information.
> new (require('.').ExampleReporter)()
Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor BaseReporter cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

Comment: In a environment without `rollout` but using `tsc` as transpiler, setting `compilerOptions.target = "ES6"` fixes the issue. But it doesn;t help for the TSdx build. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set `--target node` to fix the issue (since the default value is `browser`).

```
$ npx tsdx build --target node
```

Alternatively you can add a Babel configuration file `.babelrc` to your TDdx project and setup your target environment.

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", { "targets": { "esmodules": true } }]
  ]
}
```