# (Laravel/Vue/Tiptap) TypeError: Class constructor cannot be invoked without 'new'"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, class

I'm developing an application in Laravel/Vue, and for one particular component I require a customised version of an extension "Mention" to the text editor package "Tiptap". I have created a new class in a separate .js file which extends Mention to include the functionality I need like so:

```
import { Mention } from 'tiptap-extensions';

export default class SpecialMention extends Mention {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    get name() {
        //
    }
    get schema() {
        //
    }
}
```

An object is constructed in the code like so:

```
import SpecialMention from './SpecialMention';

new SpecialMention({
    matcher: {
        char: '@',
        allowSpaces: true,
        startOfLine: false,
    },
    items: vm.prepareItems(vm.properties, "property"),
    ...extensionFunctions
}),
```

While the code compiles without issues, I am confronted with the following runtime error:

```
"TypeError: Class constructor Mention cannot be invoked without 'new'"
```

I have seen this issue raised before, and they tend to point to Babel as the cause. Unfortunately, I am completely unfamiliar with Babel. I have tried rolling it back, with no success, and configured targets.esmodules and targets.node to true as per [the solution to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860043/javascript-es6-typeerror-class-constructor-client-cannot-be-invoked-without-ne) like so (in package.json):

```
"babel": {
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "node": true,
                    "esmodules": true
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"
    ]
}
```

Here is the transpiled code - the failure is on the last line:

```
  function SpecialMention() {
    _classCallCheck(this, SpecialMention);

    return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, _getPrototypeOf(SpecialMention).apply(this, arguments));
  }
```

However, I still get the same runtime error. Does anyone what the solution might be? Thanks very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript ES6 TypeError: Class constructor Client cannot be invoked without 'new'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860043/javascript-es6-typeerror-class-constructor-client-cannot-be-invoked-without-ne)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but no, that's the specific solution I referred to in my question that didn't work (apologies, I should have just linked it). Neither setting targets.esmodules to true or targets.node to true make any difference.