# Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Class constructor Node cannot be invoked without 'new'"

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuetify.js, tiptap

#### Bug

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Class constructor Node cannot be invoked without 'new'"

#### app.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <tiptap-vuetify
      v-model="content"
      :extensions="extensions" />

  </v-container>
</template>
 
<script>

// import the component and the necessary extensions
import { TiptapVuetify, Heading, Bold, Italic, Strike, Underline, Code, Paragraph, BulletList, OrderedList, ListItem, Link, Blockquote, HardBreak, HorizontalRule, History ,TodoList,TodoItem} from 'tiptap-vuetify'
 
export default {
  // specify TiptapVuetify component in "components"
  components: { TiptapVuetify },

  data: () => ({
    content: `
      <h3>TIPTAP</h3>`,
    // declare extensions you want to use
    extensions: [
      History,
      Blockquote,
      Link,
      Underline,
      Strike,
      Italic,
      ListItem,
      BulletList,
      OrderedList,
      [Heading, {
        options: {
          levels: [1, 2, 3]
        }
      }],
      Bold,
      Code,
      HorizontalRule,
      Paragraph,
      HardBreak,
      TodoList,
      [TodoItem, {
        options: {nested: true}
      }],],  
  }),}
</script>
```

#### System information

- OS: Windows10
- version of Node.js:v14.15.1

#### Dependencies

- "core-js": "^3.6.5",
- "tiptap-vuetify": "^2.24.0",
- "vue": "^2.6.11",
- "vuetify": "^2.2.11"

#### repo

[todo-List issue](https://github.com/qwtfy/tiptap-vuetify)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do the following to force tiptap to transpile.

```js
# vue.config.js

transpileDependencies: [
    /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]tiptap.*/
],
```

The reason why we get this error is because we try to extend a native class with a transpiled class.

References:

- [TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51860850/1259696)
- [TipTap](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/issues/521#issuecomment-698250601)