# NodeJS v15.7.0 | Electron v11.2.3 | Uncaught Error: Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor <Class> cannot be invoked without 'new', but is?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

The following `webPreferences` properties are enabled in the `BrowserWindow` Object I created:

```js
{
    webPreferences:
            {
                nodeIntegration:false,
                enableRemoteModule:false,
                contextIsolation:true,
                worldSafeExecuteJavaScript:true,
                preload:path.join(__dirname,"preload.js"),
                webSecurity:true,
                webviewTag:false,
                allowRunningInsecureContent:false,
                nodeIntegrationInSubFrames:false,
                nodeIntegrationInWorker:false,
            }
}
```

My `preload.ts`:

```
electron.contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "someapiname",
    {
        requireClass(): any
        {
            return require("path/to/module").ClassName
        }
    }
)
```

My HTML file loads a Script called `html.js`, which contains:

```js
(function()
{
    const CLASSNAME = window["someapiname"].requireClass()
    const newclass = new CLASSNAME("some param",3)
    newclass.aRandomMethod()
})()
```

But in the Developer Console of Electron I always get:

> Uncaught Error: Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor CLASSNAME cannot be invoked without 'new'

I don't get it...It asks for the `new` but IT is there? Is there something I don't know or some kind of restriction of Electron (and no, I do not want `nodeIntegration` to be set to true and any other harmful options like `enableRemoteModule`)

There's no problem when I create the class in the `preload` script, but then the methods of the Class go missing. I can only access the properties. I also tried it with that `IpcMain` and `IpcRenderer` but I got a different Error (something with Parameter).

I just want to create a Class in the renderer and use its methods.

Comment: I wonder if it's something to do with the fact that the class is a commonJS module in Node, which won't work nicely in the renderer since it might expect an es6 module. Maybe examine the nature of this exported class. I think I would be hesitant to export an entire class, but I don't know your use case

Comment: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860043/javascript-es6-typeerror-class-constructor-client-cannot-be-invoked-without-ne)

Answer (score 2):

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/context-bridge#parameter--error--return-type-support

It explicitly states you cannot copy classes / ctors via contextBridge.

> Prototype modifications are dropped. Sending classes or constructors will not work.