# TypeError: Class constructor Dropdown cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I am a beginner to ReactJS or even Javascript. I have tried to create a class component of Dropdown like my other class components of Nav bars etc. When I add the dropdown component in Index.js file it shows me the above error. I have tried ReactJs Bootstrap and it returns the same error

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Dropdown extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {  }
    }
    render() { 
        return ( 
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">{this.props.name}</button>
            {this.props.listofitems.map((item)=>(AddItems(item)))}
        </div>
         );
    }
}
 function AddItems(params) {
     return(
         
   
            <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a >{params}</a>
            </div>
    
     );
     
 }
export default Dropdown;
```

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
     <Nav />
     <IntroBar/>
    {/* <MultipleTutObj/> */ }
    <Dropdown listofitems={['Red','Yellow','Green']} name="Drop"/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript ES6 TypeError: Class constructor Client cannot be invoked without 'new'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860043/javascript-es6-typeerror-class-constructor-client-cannot-be-invoked-without-ne)

Comment: How do you change the bable Configuration from ES5 to ES6?

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/setting-up-react-for-es6-with-webpack-and-babel-2.html

look at the webpack config