# Cannot login into RabbitMQ management

Tags: rabbitmq

It's accessible at localhost:15672. I set up a user admin:password, granted permissions, enabled rabbitmqctl management.
In management console I see this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor ShiftedDate cannot be invoked without 'new'
at Function.Sammy.log (sammy-0.7.6.min.js:5:1689)
at Sammy.Application.log (sammy-0.7.6.min.js:5:8381)
at Sammy.Application.error (sammy-0.7.6.min.js:5:16746)
at Sammy.Application.notFound (sammy-0.7.6.min.js:5:16392)
at Sammy.Application.runRoute (sammy-0.7.6.min.js:5:14714)
at Sammy.Application._checkLocation (sammy-0.7.6.min.js:5:17004)
at Sammy.Application.run (sammy-0.7.6.min.js:5:11353)
at start_app_login (main.js:76:13)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js:13:9)
at e (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:30005)
```

What could be the issue? RabbitMQ version 3.10.2, Windows 10 machine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript ES6 TypeError: Class constructor Client cannot be invoked without 'new'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860043/javascript-es6-typeerror-class-constructor-client-cannot-be-invoked-without-ne)  (But I am not sue, because you did not share _COMPLETE_ error message, and a [mre])

Comment: No, it does not, because I did not compile any of this, it's the RabbitMQ issue. It's not my code that is not running.

Comment: More info is needed, because with current info this is not reproducible. A [standard install](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows-manual.html)  (But I used `choco install rabbitmq`), followed by `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`, which will  make rabbitmq accessible at localhost:15672, which makes it possible to create a new `admin` user.   After this: I cannot reproduce this problem...

Comment: BTW: Do you have a good reason to install 3.10.2, while 3.10.4 is  [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html), and 3.10.5 was released 2 days ago ?

Comment: Reinstalling rabbitmq with choco solved the issue. Initial installation was with the official installer.

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error on Mac after installing the Docker image, and it was caused by a browser extension (Change Timezone for Google Chrome)

Other browser extensions that affect your browser's timezone may also affect this, try incognito/private/another browser first

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling rabbitmq with chocolatey solves the issue.

Comment: Considering that chocolatey uses the official installer under the hood, my guess is that something in your environment or how you ran the official installer was the actual cause.

Comment: Actually, reinstallation with chocolatey fixed it only partially. Sometimes I can log in, sometimes not. I am not sure what is the issue.