# Response not successful: Received status code 500 when using `datasources`

Tags: apollo, apollo-server

Here's my server setup:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  dataSources: () => ({
    movieAPI: new MovieAPI()
  }),
  context: {
    hello: `world`
  }
});

server
  .listen({ port: 4000 })
  .then(({ url }) => console.log(` app running at ${url}`));
```

If I remove `datasources` everything works fine, otherwise I get an error in `graphql playground` `"error": "Response not successful: Received status code 500"`

I'm doing this [Apollo Server tutorial](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/introduction.html) but I have some babel config so I can use es6 syntax.

Here is my [repo](https://github.com/kstulgys/tmdb-apollo-react/blob/master/server/src/index.js)

Comment: I'm facing similar issues. I'm using axios for now. Check this link out, it might be helpful
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1828

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `introspection: true` solved the issue

Comment: Can you please be more specific.  Adding introspection where?

Comment: Although the solution didn't work for me, `introspection: true` is an option in the ApolloServer config. [See Here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/testing/graphql-playground/)

Answer (score 4):

in playground GUI there is a button: `COPY CURL`
if you try it in the terminal you can get more details about the error.
I had same problem and I got this response from curl:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Class constructor DataSource cannot be invoked without 'new'",
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "stacktrace": [
            "TypeError: Class constructor DataSource cannot be invoked without 'new'",
            "    at new UserAPI (/var/www/html/blog-project/server/src/datasources/user.ts:12:5)",
            "    at Object.dataSources (/var/www/html/blog-project/server/src/index.ts:30:14)",
            "    at /var/www/html/blog-project/server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/src/requestPipeline.ts:618:34",
            "    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)",
            "    at /var/www/html/blog-project/server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:8:71",
            "    at new Promise (<anonymous>)",
            "    at __awaiter (/var/www/html/blog-project/server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:4:12)",
            "    at initializeDataSources (/var/www/html/blog-project/server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:323:20)",
            "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/blog-project/server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/src/requestPipeline.ts:117:9)",
            "    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)",
            "    at /var/www/html/blog-project/server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:8:71",
            "    at new Promise (<anonymous>)",
            "    at __awaiter (/var/www/html/blog-project/server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:4:12)",
            "    at Object.processGraphQLRequest (/var/www/html/blog-project/server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:41:12)",
            "    at /var/www/html/blog-project/server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/src/runHttpQuery.ts:310:32",
            "    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

after search about `Class constructor DataSource cannot be invoked without 'new'` I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50203532/5077529)

> This problem should be solved in Node.js by setting TypeScript target option to es6. Modern Node.js versions support ES6 classes, there is no need to transpile them.

so the solution: in `tsconfig.json` setting *target* to **es6**

Answer (score 0):

in the setting of playground change `request.credentials: "omit"`, to `"request.credentials": "include"`.

Answer (score 0):

For those using TypeScript and the Serverless Framework with AWS:

Make sure your `tsconfig.json` has the `compilerOptions.target` set to `"es6"` and `compilerOptions.module` set to `"CommonJS"`.

It looks like this could be an issue with over-transpiling code([ref](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/2216#issuecomment-460275888)). So we need to set `"target": "es6"` as to include the `class` keyword. This presents a problem with the use of es6 modules, hence the need for the `"module": "CommonJS"` in the `tsconfig.json`

Full `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": ".build",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2015"],
    "rootDir": "./",
    "module": "CommonJS"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you could have **provided the error stack trace** with the question then it would have been great!

There could be **many reasons** for why you got the 500 response from the apollo server but I am just gonna talk about the general reasons. For others, who are still facing this issue. Mostly, this should be an issue with the way you are **creating and connecting the datasource** to the apollo server. Please, look at the **stacktrace of the error** and for resolving the issue.