# TypeScript ECMAScript target for NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

For performance purposes, compatibility, and scalability, which is the best [ECMAScript target](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) for the compiler TypeScript to use in a module with NodeJS?

According to [NodeJS ES6 (ECMAScript 2015)](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/) is not fully supported. Is it worth to use [ES6](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) or is it better for the compatibility to add the target [ES5](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) with the associated workarounds generated automatically by Typescript?

On other hand, at this moment these are the **in-progress** functions in NodeJS for ES6:

```
  --harmony-do-expressions (enable "harmony do-expressions" (in progress))
  --harmony-class-fields (enable "harmony fields in class literals" (in progress))
  --harmony-static-fields (enable "harmony static fields in class literals" (in progress))
  --harmony-array-flatten (enable "harmony Array.prototype.flat{ten,Map}" (in progress))
  --harmony-locale (enable "Intl.Locale" (in progress))
```

I don't know if I need these features at this moment but for the maintainability of the code maybe it is not the best option.

Comment: Since you can increase performance by sacrificing compatibility, this is very much a matter of opinion.

Comment: It wasn't an answer, it was pointed out that you were asking for something which is "primarily opinion-based" and thus off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js [fully supports ECMAScript 2015](https://node.green/#ES2015), with the exception of [tail call optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260390/node-js-tail-call-optimization-possible-or-not) and [ES modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) (experimental support is available with a flag and .mjs extension).

It doesn't make sense to transpile to ES5 with TypeScript in Node, TypeScript doesn't follow the specs strictly and can also have its limitations, notably [the extension of native ES6 classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50203532/3731501).

Comment: Thank you! Then the best way it would be to use ES6.

Comment: That's correct. More specifically, ES2018, Node supports it with aforementioned exceptions (the closest target in TS is `es2017`).